# Relational operator and array index

Tags: matlab

```
x=[15 -8 15 4];  
y=[-3 8 13 4];

z=y(x>y)

z =
    -3    13
```

It seems like I'm getting confused with array index concept.
Please explain the output.

Comment: What did you expect instead? You are selecting those values of `y` at which corresponding index the values of `x` are larger than those in `y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this try looking at the intermediate output of each step of the operation.

`x=[15 -8 15 4];`
`y=[-3 8 13 4];`
`result1 = x > y`
`result1 = [1 0 1 0]`
`z = y([1 0 1 0])`
`z = [-3 13]`

The comparison `x > y` actually returns a logical array that is then applied to `y` to pull out the elements at the non-zero values.  This is different than array indexing where you access an array element by its index value, e.g. `y(3)`.